# Can not add ScriptMananger to page with out getting error from auto generated code to the designer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use a script mananger to use page methods to communicate between the server and client side of my page. I have added this code to the html

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"   
  EnablePageMethods="True">
```

When I add this, here is what is inserted into the designer page.

```
 Protected WithEvents ScriptManager1 As Global.System.Web.UI.ScriptManager
```

But when this is automatically added, i get this error.

```
Error   52  Type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' is not defined.  C:\Users\Bill\Desktop\iPlan-7-layer\listing\summarytreeMain.aspx.designer.vb    32  44  iPlan
```

I added a reference in my project to system.web.services - but still can not seem to get around this error. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: ScriptManager Enables AJAX In Your Web Apps.
Are you want to use any AJAX UpdatePanel kind of stuff?

Comment: What I'm attempting to do is convert our existing web app so that it works with all browsers, right now (it is a pharma app, so was based off IE) - I am trying to use page methods for browsers other than IE, since the original developer used RemoteScripting (RS.execute) which will not work in other browsers. (also changed hundreds of references from document.all to document.getElementById - this app is pretty old)

Comment: If it helps, I am also getting this error just by dropping script manager from the toolbar onto the designer.

Comment: would i need to download and install the ajax toolkit to use this? http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/download.ashx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference to System.Web.Extensions is probably missing in your project. I get the error when I remove it.